# Script does not work in LinuxMint , works in Windows

Tags: php, linux, windows

I have this weirdly misbehaving script. It runs normal in Windows 7 ( Easy PHP 12.0 , PHP 5.4.4 , Apache 2.4.2 ) , but it doesn't work in LinuxMint 13 ( Apache 2.2.22 Ubuntu ) 
I know linux is case sensitive , so I double checked file paths, and I used `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, but there no errors.

```
<?php
$DumpHere='../Img/Gallery/DumpHere/';
$ThumbsFolder='../Img/Gallery/Thumbs/';
$PreviewFolder='../Img/Gallery/Preview/';
$Files=array_diff(scandir($DumpHere), array('..', '.'));

echo '<div id="FileList" >';
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($Files as $key => $list) {
    echo ("<li>".$list."</li>");
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div> <!-- closes FileList -->";

echo '<div id="WorkArea"><form action="insertGalleryTitles.php" method="post"><ul>';
foreach ($Files as $key => $Processed) {

    $filename = $DumpHere.$Processed;

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $ratio = $width/$height;
    $outputHeight = 500*$ratio;

    // Resample thumbnail
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(70, 70);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 70, $width, $height);
    // Output Thumbnail
    imagejpeg($image_p, $ThumbsFolder.'thumb_'.$Processed, 100);
    // Resample preview
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(500, $outputHeight);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, $outputHeight, $width, $height);
    // Output Preview
    imagejpeg($image_p, $PreviewFolder.'preview_'.$Processed, 100);
    echo '<li><img src="'.$ThumbsFolder.'thumb_'.$Processed.'">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="title['.$Processed.']" value="vyplň popisek">';
}


echo "</li>";

echo '</ul><input type="submit" ></form></div>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you surround your echo in parentheses? `echo ("<li>".$list."</li>");`

Comment: Do you get any errors when run under Linux? Does it just fail?

Comment: -1 `Script does not work` and `weirdly misbehaving` are not error codes, please provide us with a detailed description of nots working.

Comment: Try with error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of the script

Comment: @SSHThis There werent any errors , it just didnt do the job.It listed files in "dumphere" folder , but it didnt resample the image , nor did it create the form. No errors at all.Also here and there it detects a ghost file named ".jpg" , which i can only get rid of using terminal.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè i didnt get any errors , so i cannot give any.I used error_reporting(E_ALL) as Nevermind suggests , but no errors either.

Comment: Hm... - is it possible that you don't have gd library on server?

Comment: @nevermind Yes that was it , thank You ... i had no idea :-/